# Contexts disappearing on intent page refresh

Tags: dialogflow-es

Every time I type in an input context name in one of my intents, it disappears once I save the intent and reload the page...

I have no idea whats causing this, and I can't find any resources to help me fix this.

Suggestions?

Comment: I type the name of the context, then I press enter and my name gets embedded in a sort of bubble, and then I press the blue save button.  Are you doing it like that?

Comment: ... I'm an idiot... Thanks @Tom

Answer (score 1):

Having typed the context name you have to press ENTER. Tab, space, mouse click won't do it. It has to be ENTER.